# Total count of two different content types in one View?

Tags: views

Use case: How many Demonstrations and Deliverables are from each State?

I'm using a View with Aggregate but don't see a way add multiple content type counts.

Refer to screen capture of the page and view settings please.

[image: View on page]

[image: View settings]

Comment: How do you relate content types? Using entity reference? You need to display states and have 3 main fields, 1 as state title, 2nd and 3rd as referenced (referencing) titles of demonstrations and deliverables with aggregation. We kinda need more data.

Comment: Demonstration edit screen: http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2015/06_w27/920896/8.PNG and Deliverable edit screen: http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2015/06_w27/920897/9.PNG

Comment: There's not reference between them.

Answer (score 1):

The table in the screen capture is similar to this one:

[image]

The [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module can be used to transform that table so that the calculations in the last rows (with **Count**, **Sum** and **Max**) get added to it.

By replacing the columns like '# Fish' and 'Weight' with 'Total Demonstrations' and 'Total deliverable ...' (as in the question), and by asking for only the 'sum' to be added, it should answer the question.

To ask for the 'sum', just select it from the selection list, similar to what is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

For more details (step-by-step instructions), refer to the [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/359981) about the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module.

Disclosure: I'm a **co**-maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: I was just trying to do it this morning. Not getting the results I want.Can I correspond with you directly? sandshakimi@cvpcorp.com

Comment: The View Calc module didn't seem the right approach. Or at least I was not able to get the aggregate of two diff content types in the same View table.