# Webform live calculations in table/matrix

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms, javascript

I am trying to create a work time allocation webform. My goal is to create a table (6 columns and addable rows) and get a **live** sum of all columns at the bottom. (edit: pardon my lacking terminology.  With live I meant client side ajax or js that updates instantly when the user fills in the form, before submitting it)

I tried using a webform and webform matrix module, they allow for a table with addable rows. But I can't get the live sums to work. Is there another method or module I could use that would suite my case better?

TLDR; I need a webform with a table supporting x amount of rows and a live sum at the bottom. Any suggestions what modules to use?

The colored cells are buttons.

[image: example]

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think that is make the sum in the client side

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes sorry, I mean something client side that updates as the user fills in the form without submitting it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Filter form submission data by a field value with Views, Webform](http://othermachines.com/blog/filter-form-submission-data-field-value-views-webform) for a tutorial to display the data collected by [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) in a filterable, tabular format, using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module (of course), and the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

After you created an appropriate view, you could consider either of these approaches:

1. Add the "[Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc)" module to add the "live sums" that you're looking for. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

   > This module adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the Views module.
   >
   > You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines calculated rows).

   And this is a typical screenprint using the Views Calc module:

   [image]

   Refer to my answer to "[Total count of two different content types in one View?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163561/total-count-of-two-different-content-types-in-one-view)" for more details about how to use the Views Calc module.

   Disclosure: I'm a **co**-maintainer of this module,
   I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).
2. Use the [Views Summarize](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_summarize) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

   > Enables an extra display style which displays summaries of a column on the last row.

   There isn't a lot (any?) documentation available about actually using this module, but the "clue" is like so: Click on the "settings" icon for the display style, then enable a summarizer on one of the columns.

   Refer to the [project's home page](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_summarize) for a screenprint of a view using this module.
3. Addd the calculation via custom logic in **views templates**, as explained in one of the answers to the question about "[How can I add a summary row to a Drupal View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011505/how-can-i-add-a-summary-row-to-a-drupal-view)". Here is a quote from that answer:

   > ... Create a `views-view.tpl.php` for your view, and then edit it calculate and print out the summary.
   >
   > Another option is to create another display for the same view, and then create a `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` and calculate and print out the summary w/o doing a print $row; to avoid calling the fields template. Then add use view display where needed.

**Note**: the extra clarification (requirement?) about "live" only got added after I wrote most of my answer. I.e. via a comment like "*... something client side that updates as the user fills in the form without submitting it first*". So far I'm not aware of any module that ALSO supports that. Not sure if there is a way to do that using the "Views templates" approach described above (if there is such way, please add another answer related to that also).

Comment: Does this module support Ajax? I'm pretty sure OP means that by "live sums"

Comment: this is a great explanation ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer :: thanks for the nice comment!

Comment: I utilized views_calc in one project and help me a lot, and with your words I learn a bit more about his use.

Comment: Hm, interesting and thx for telling ... Note: for Views_Calc, I'm only like a "legacy maintaiiner", i.e. to renew the support for the D6 version of it (which is a prereq for the D6 version of the Chart module that I maintain ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I recently got into Drupal and web development so I am still getting used to the terminology. With live I meant something that shows the client the sums of table columns as he fills it in, before submitting the form. 

Your provided solution is actually exactly the next step I am looking to solve; an interface that totals all submitted forms for the admins. So thank you, now I know how to solve that!

Comment: I got a little eager with the problem at hand, but I took the tour now and will look further into AJAX calls in webforms.

Answer (score 0):

I found some additional resources on AJAX and manipulating a webform before submitting it. It is not a complete solution but if anyone is on the same path it might be of use. Thanks to @Pierre.Vriens for pointing me in the right direction.

[The tutorial is here.](http://1013.fi/cms/interactive-drupal-web-forms-jquery-javascript-library)